# How to remove Wine program entries from the "Open With" list?

Tags: wine, uninstall

I have a seemingly simple problem that's been bugging me for a while now. I have installed wine at some previous point, and I am offered to choose from shortlist, when I right click a suitable program, to run it by Wine. However, there are newer versions available from the one that I am offered. I would like to uninstall this version, and instead use a new one. However, it is NOT installed as software package, which impedes solution. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Actually it is not. I have tried this, but "wine uninstaller" offers me to remove programs from Wine. I seek to uninstall Wine itself. Problem is, it is not installed as a software package. At the same time, it is offered to me in the right click menu. I would like to uninstall it completely, or else replace it in right click menu with other and newer instances of wine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
   sudo apt-get purge wine
```